# How can i prevent duplicate username properties in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to make sure that the username in my database is unique

in firebase, the authentication for my app is for email and password
but I want to check the username field..

Comment: Firebase authentication doesn't provide a username field. You have to create that yourself on your database of choice and then check that database to see if the username already exists when a new user enters their preferred username.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement it manually since firebase auth doesn't support saving usernames by itself.

Every time a user did authenticate inside your app, you can save his username in a document if it doesn't exist already in the database:

```
  Future<void> registerUsername(String username) async {
  // we check first if the username doesn't exists (is not registered)
  if(!await doesUsernameExistsAlready(username)) {
    
    // then, we register it.
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('usersInfo').doc("usernames").set({
     username: true,
    }, SetOptions(merge: true) );

    // otherwise we print that it exists already
    } else {
     print("$username already exists");
    }



 // we check a username existence with this method
 Future<bool> doesUsernameExistsAlready(String username) async { 

   // we get the registered usernames from our database
   final usernames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('usersInfo').doc("usernames").get();
   final data = usernames.data() as Map<String, dynamic> 

   // we return that if a key with that username exists
   return data.containsKey(username);
 }
```

Comment: I advise to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) in this case.